# Graphql Subscription not working for graphql_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, graphql-subscriptions, graphql-flutter

I am trying to use `subscriptions` in my app, when I add a user using `mutation` ,`mysubscription` is fired. When I try to add user using `mutation` from my `flutter` app , `mysubscription` of backend is fired but the `subscription` of my `flutter` app does not

I don't see any error in my app. Check [video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pritishsawant-16.appspot.com/o/Screen%20Recording%202024-02-16%20at%209.15.01%20PM.mov?alt=media&token=06d5ba59-9016-44dd-aaf5-1535d5fcd687) for more context

Here is my code

```
ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> clientFor({
  required String uri,
  required String subscriptionUri,
}) {
  final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
    uri,
  );

  final WebSocketLink websocketLink = WebSocketLink(
    subscriptionUri,
    config: const SocketClientConfig(
      autoReconnect: true,
      inactivityTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
    ),
    subProtocol: GraphQLProtocol.graphqlWs,
  );
  // authLink.concat(
  final Link link = httpLink.split(
      (request) => request.isSubscription, websocketLink, httpLink);

  return ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient>(
    GraphQLClient(
      cache: GraphQLCache(store: HiveStore()),
      link: link,
    ),
  );
}

/// Wraps the root application with the `graphql_flutter` client.
/// We use the cache for all state management.
class ClientProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  ClientProvider({
    super.key,
    @required this.child,
    required String uri,
    required String subscriptionUri,
  }) : client = clientFor(
          uri: uri,
          subscriptionUri: subscriptionUri,
        );

  final Widget? child;
  final ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GraphQLProvider(
      client: client,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

I have wrapped `MaterialApp` with `ClientProvider`

```
return ClientProvider(
      subscriptionUri: "ws://localhost:4000/graphql",
      uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',....
```

Then MyHomePage widget is as follows

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> items = [];

  String addUser = """
    mutation AddUser(\$input: AddUserInput!) {
    addUser(user: \$input) {
      name
      id
      
    }
  }
""";

 

  String mySubscription = """
  subscription mySubscription {
    newUser {
      name
    }
  }
""";

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your text',
            ),
          ),
          Mutation(
            options: MutationOptions(
              document: gql(addUser),
              update: (cache, result) {
                // debugPrint("Mutation Cache: ${cache.toString()}");
                // debugPrint("Mutation Result: ${result.toString()}");
              },
              onError: (error) {
                debugPrint("Mutation Error ${error}");
              },
              onCompleted: (resultData) {
                if (resultData != null) {
                  // context.showMessageDialog("${resultData['register']['firstName']}");

                  // debugPrint("Mutation data" + resultData.toString());
                }
              },
            ),
            builder: (runMutation, queryResult) {
              return TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  runMutation(<String, dynamic>{
                    "input": {
                      "name": _controller.text,
                      "likes": 3,
                      "movies": ["Star Wars"],
                      "isMale": true,
                      "money": 12.23
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: const Text("Submit User"),
              );
            },
          ),
        
          Subscription(
            options: SubscriptionOptions(
              document: gql(mySubscription),
            ),
            builder: ((QueryResult result) {
              if (result.hasException) {
                return Text("Error occured: " +
                    result.exception!.graphqlErrors[0].message);
              }

              if (result.isLoading) {
                return Center(
                  child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }

              debugPrint(result.data.toString());

              return ResultAccumulator.appendUniqueEntries(
                latest: result.data,
                builder: (context, {results}) => Text(results![0].toString()),
              );
            }),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using both Protocols `GraphQLProtocol.graphqlWs` & `GraphQLProtocol.graphqlTransportWs` but same issue.

My `subscriptions` work in `react native` with `apollo client`

`Subscription` should occur in flutter app as well when add user `mutation` occurs but it doesn't. `Subscription` does work on backend when I try to add a user from `flutter` app with `mutation`. I don't see any error in logs

Comment: Worked after following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0-x2zlBD4c

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to the lifecycle of your WebSocket connection. The connection might be closing before the subscription can receive any data.

One way to debug this is to add a keepAliveMessage to your SocketClientConfig. This will send a message to the server every inactivityTimeout to keep the connection alive.

If this doesn't solve your issue, it might be helpful to add more logging to your server to see when and why the WebSocket connection is closed.